# wordpress upload theme The link you followed has expired. (already set_time limit 400 )

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I have got my customised theme and upload to Wordress site. When it comes to upload the zip file at Appearance > Theme , it says  The link you followed has expired.

Could you please tell what else I should after setting these parameters at wp-config.php ?

..

```
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '259M');
set_time_limit(400);
```

My zip upload size is 142 MB

Comment: You could just transfer it through your FTP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase `upload_max_filesize`. You can do this using any of the following methods:

**1. htaccess file:**

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 150M
php_value post_max_size 150M
```

**2. php.ini file:**

```
upload_max_filesize = 150M
post_max_size = 150M
```

**3. Theme's function.php file or wp-config.php:**

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '150M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '150M');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have tried it first in local wordpress installation. Then you may continue with uploading the entire content to server using FTP clients.

I can suggest another option to use file manager to upload the theme into **wp-content/themes** folder.

If they doesn't work, you can change the values in CPanel for max_file_upload and use a suitable value.

Comment: Also, check the following values in the server:memory_limit
upload_max_size
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
max_execution_time
max_input_time

Answer (score 0):

In `ubuntu 20.04`, `WordPress 5.8`, `PHP 7.4` you have to increase `upload_max_filesize` on your `php.ini` file so run:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

After that find `upload_max_filesize` by `CTRL+w` and then change this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

TO

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Then save the file by `CTRL+o` and then `CTRL+x` to close the file.

Finally, restart your apache:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

And try again in your WordPress admin.